# Kivy, weakly-referenced object no longer exists

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

This is my kv file

```
<GetAccount>:
    Button:
        id: refresh
        ang: 0
        background_normal: 'static/refresh.png'
        size_hint: None, None
        size: sp(50), sp(50)
        pos_hint: {'center_y': .96, 'center_x': .8} 
        on_press: root.clean()
        canvas.before:
            Rotate:
                angle: self.ang
                origin: self.center
```

some logic and dynamic contents in python code

```
class GetAccount(FloatLayout):

    keyandnick = ObjectProperty(KeyAndNick())
    account = ObjectProperty(Account())

    def __init__(self, **kargs):
        super(GetAccount, self).__init__(**kargs)
        layout = StackLayout(size_hint_y=None)
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
        nicks = self.keyandnick.get_nicks()
        for nick in nicks:
            layout.add_widget(Button(text=str(nick[0]), size_hint_y=None, height=sp(60), on_press=self.ask_for_key))
        scroll = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, .9), bar_width=sp(5), bar_inactive_color=[.7, .7, .7, .5])
        scroll.add_widget(layout)
        self.add_widget(scroll)

    def ask_for_key(self, obj):
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.account_name = obj.text
        boxlayout = BoxLayout(size_hint=(1, .4), orientation='vertical', pos_hint={'center_y': .5})
        self.key = TextInput(pos_hint={'center_y': .5}, hint_text='Key', font_size=sp(30), password=True)
        boxlayout.add_widget(self.key)
        boxlayout.add_widget(Button(text='Get Account', font_size=sp(30), on_press=self.get_account))
        boxlayout.add_widget(Button(text='Delete Account', pos_hint={'center_x': .5}, font_size=sp(30), on_press=self.delete_account))
        popup = Popup(title=self.account_name, content=boxlayout, size_hint=(1, .7))
        popup.bind(on_dismiss=self.clear)
        popup.open()

    def get_account(self, obj):
        if self.keyandnick.check_key(self.key.text):
            self.clear_widgets()
            boxlayout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', size_hint=(1, .6), pos_hint={'center_y': .5})
            _account = self.account.get_account(self.account_name)
            a = True
            for data in _account:
                if a:
                    boxlayout.add_widget(Label(text=data, font_size=sp(30), bold=True, underline=True))
                    a = False
                else:
                    boxlayout.add_widget(Label(text=data, font_size=sp(20)))
            popup = Popup(title=self.account_name, content=boxlayout, size_hint=(1, .7))
            popup.open()
        else:
            self.key.background_color = [0, 0, 255, 0.3]

    def clean(self):
        animation = Animation(ang=360)
        animation.start(self.ids.refresh)
        animation.bind(on_complete=self.clear)

    def clear(self, a, b):
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.add_widget(GetAccount())

    def delete_account(self, obj):
        if self.keyandnick.check_key(self.key.text):
            self.account.delete_account(self.account_name)
            self.keyandnick.del_nick(self.account_name)
        else:
            self.key.background_color = [0, 0, 255, 0.3]
```

when i pressed button which has id -> refresh (defined in kv) it works fine but in third time it gives error:

> Exception in thread Thread-1:  Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
>        self.run()    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
>        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)    File "/home/ubuntu/.py-3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kivy/input/providers/mtdev.py",
>   line 197, in _thread_run
>        _device = Device(_fn)    File "/home/ubuntu/.py-3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kivy/lib/mtdev.py",
>   line 131, in **init**
>        self._fd = os.open(filename, os.O_NONBLOCK | os.O_RDONLY)  PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/input/event6'
>   animation = Animation(ang=360) animation.start(self.ids.refresh)
>   animation.bind(on_complete=self.clear) animation end.
>   
>    animation =
>   Animation(ang=360) animation.start(self.ids.refresh)
>   animation.bind(on_complete=self.clear) animation end.
>   
>    [INFO   ] [Base
>   ] Leaving application in progress...  Traceback (most recent call
>   last):    File "main.py", line 146, in 
>        AccountMaintainerApp().run()    File "/home/ubuntu/.py-3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line
>   824, in run
>        runTouchApp()    File "/home/ubuntu/.py-3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kivy/base.py",
>   line 487, in runTouchApp
>        EventLoop.window.mainloop()    File "/home/ubuntu/.py-3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py",
>   line 525, in mainloop
>        self._mainloop()    File "/home/ubuntu/.py-3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py",
>   line 290, in _mainloop
>        EventLoop.idle()    File "/home/ubuntu/.py-3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kivy/base.py",
>   line 327, in idle
>        Clock.tick()    File "/home/ubuntu/.py-3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kivy/clock.py",
>   line 483, in tick
>        self._process_events()    File "/home/ubuntu/.py-3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kivy/clock.py",
>   line 615, in _process_events
>        event.tick(self._last_tick, remove)    File "/home/ubuntu/.py-3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kivy/clock.py",
>   line 374, in tick
>        ret = callback(self._dt)    File "/home/ubuntu/.py-3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kivy/animation.py",
>   line 342, in _update
>        self.stop(widget)    File "/home/ubuntu/.py-3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kivy/animation.py",
>   line 213, in stop
>        self.cancel(widget)    File "/home/ubuntu/.py-3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kivy/animation.py",
>   line 222, in cancel
>        self._widgets.pop(widget.uid, None)    File "kivy/weakproxy.pyx", line 19, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.**getattr**
>   (/tmp/pip-build-zy75v30v/kivy/kivy/weakproxy.c:1097)    File
>   "kivy/weakproxy.pyx", line 15, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.**ref**
>   (/tmp/pip-build-zy75v30v/kivy/kivy/weakproxy.c:1004)  ReferenceError:
>   weakly-referenced object no longer exists

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61777718

Answer (score 3):

[Programming Guide » Kv language](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html)

> An id is a weakref to the widget and not the widget itself. As a consequence, storing the id is not sufficient to keep the widget from being garbage collected.
>
> To keep the widget alive, a direct reference to the id *refresh* must be kept. This is achieved using *id.__self__* or *refresh.__self__* in this case.

## kv file

```
<GetAccount>:
    refresh: refresh.__self__
    Button:
        id: refresh
        ang: 0
        background_normal: 'static/refresh.png'
        size_hint: None, None
        size: sp(50), sp(50)
        pos_hint: {'center_y': .96, 'center_x': .8}
        on_press: root.clean()
        canvas.before:
            Rotate:
                angle: self.ang
                origin: self.center
```

Comment: ok i got it. one more thing when i press this button which has id: refresh the whole content rotates but i just gave id of button in animation.start(self.ids.refresh) why is that?

Comment: Animation and AnimationTransition are used to animate Widget properties. The id of the button is a reference to the button widget. Therefore, it rotates the button.

Comment: This worked for me at the time, but the next day, I ran the same program with no changes and this same error occured