# Kivy : Error weakly-referenced object (in a clock function) no longer exists

Tags: python, android, garbage-collection, kivy, weak-references

So here is my error code
I think there's something hard in this error, i looked on forums but couldn't find out.

And ... i have the error **on my phone** (with [kivy launcher python 3](https://github.com/kivy/kivy-launcher) and when i build with buildozer) **but not on my computer** (ubuntu 18.0.4 and windows 10)
The error, from what i understand, comes from the garbage collector that delete a reference and the code try to access the reference after the garbage collector. but i am not sure if I rly understand the garbage collector thing

**What i tried :**

- make "strong references" so the gc dont delete it with:

```
    id: id.__self__
```

in my kv file

- make "strong references" with :

```
     self.refs = [
                self.id.__self__,
                self.id.__self__]
```

-Use the ErrorHandler to handle the error but the error keep coming for ever

**What I think cause the error but I have no idea how to fix it:**

- the clock I use to send request to the server but i don't know why (self.requestClient is a function to send a request) :

  C = Clock.schedule_interval(self.requestClient, 5)
- this information in the [kivy clock documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html?highlight=clock#module-kivy.clock) :

> Important
>
> The callback is weak-referenced: you are responsible for keeping a
>   reference to your original object/callback. If you don’t keep a
>   reference, the ClockBase will never execute your callback

Error :

```
[ERROR  ] Exception catched by ExceptionHandler
05-07 11:27:45.694  2788  2823 I python  : Traceback (most recent call last):
05-07 11:27:45.694  2788  2823 I python  :   File path/kivy-launcher/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/launcher/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 747, in mainloop
05-07 11:27:45.694  2788  2823 I python  :   File "/path/kivy-launcher/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/launcher/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 479, in _mainloop
05-07 11:27:45.694  2788  2823 I python  :   File "/path/kivy-launcher/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/launcher/kivy/base.py", line 339, in idle
05-07 11:27:45.694  2788  2823 I python  :   File "/path/kivy-launcher/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/launcher/kivy/clock.py", line 591, in tick
05-07 11:27:45.694  2788  2823 I python  :   File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 384, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
05-07 11:27:45.694  2788  2823 I python  :   File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 414, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
05-07 11:27:45.694  2788  2823 I python  :   File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 412, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
05-07 11:27:45.694  2788  2823 I python  :   File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 154, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick
05-07 11:27:45.694  2788  2823 I python  :   File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 86, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.get_callback
05-07 11:27:45.694  2788  2823 I python  :   File "/path/kivy-launcher/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/launcher/kivy/weakmethod.py", line 56, in is_dead
05-07 11:27:45.694  2788  2823 I python  : ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists
```

Thanks for reading !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The official documentation ([Kv language Programming Guide](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#referencing-widgets)) says to add 'strong' references such as `id_name: id_name.__self__` in the KV code, but it is unclear where this is necessary. What's more, it did not solve the `ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists` errors for me.

What *did* work is forcing Buildozer to use a specific version of `hostpython3` by adding this to the `requirements` line of the buildozer.spec file:

```
python3==3.7.5, hostpython3==3.7.5
```

One more note: after adding the above to `requirements`, I went back and removed all my `__self__` references and it still worked fine, so apparently these are no longer needed in Kivy KV language.

Credit for this goes to [the beautiful answer from leo10011](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61686587).

**Update 2020-05-19**: This bug [reportedly has been fixed](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/1089#issuecomment-629776092) in Kivy 2.0.

Comment: Thanks. To make this work, I had to delete my `.buildozer` directory, in order to rebuild the app.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do to keep a reference to e.g. `my_object` is to add `my_object: my_object.__self__` line in the `kv` part of my `root` rule.

Since you haven't provide any code, I can't be more specific...

Comment: Hi, i did do what you say but not in my root object (in a screen), does it matters ? I can't really show my code, sorry for that

Comment: @Biloba It might matter, but I can't tell.. You can try to post a [mcve]..