# ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists while trying to deploy app with buildozer/kivy

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

Yesterday I deployed my app on android with buildozer and everythng was fine today I made some little changes and tried to see them on my phone, but I got this error throught buildozer logcat:

```
03-22 22:15:06.055 18359 18424 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
03-22 22:15:06.055 18359 18424 I python  :    File "/home/bruno/SportTimerMD/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 201, in <module>
03-22 22:15:06.055 18359 18424 I python  :    File "/home/bruno/SportTimerMD/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/sporttimermd/kivy/app.py", line 855, in run
03-22 22:15:06.055 18359 18424 I python  :    File "/home/bruno/SportTimerMD/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/sporttimermd/kivy/base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
03-22 22:15:06.056 18359 18424 I python  :    File "/home/bruno/SportTimerMD/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/sporttimermd/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 747, in mainloop
03-22 22:15:06.056 18359 18424 I python  :    File "/home/bruno/SportTimerMD/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/sporttimermd/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 479, in _mainloop
03-22 22:15:06.056 18359 18424 I python  :    File "/home/bruno/SportTimerMD/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/sporttimermd/kivy/base.py", line 339, in idle
03-22 22:15:06.056 18359 18424 I python  :    File "/home/bruno/SportTimerMD/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/sporttimermd/kivy/clock.py", line 591, in tick
03-22 22:15:06.056 18359 18424 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 384, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
03-22 22:15:06.057 18359 18424 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 414, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
03-22 22:15:06.057 18359 18424 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 412, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
03-22 22:15:06.057 18359 18424 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 154, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick
03-22 22:15:06.057 18359 18424 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 86, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.get_callback
03-22 22:15:06.057 18359 18424 I python  :    File "/home/bruno/SportTimerMD/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/sporttimermd/kivy/weakmethod.py", line 56, in is_dead
03-22 22:15:06.057 18359 18424 I python  :  ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists
03-22 22:15:06.057 18359 18424 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

I tried to change osx.kivy_version from 1.9.1 to 2.0.0 in buildozer .spec file but it didnt helped. What should I do?
I also got this warning:

```
03-22 22:15:05.606 18359 18424 I python  : [WARNING] Deprecated property "<AliasProperty name=filename>" of object "<kivy.core.audio.audio_sdl2.SoundSDL2 object at 0xca76def8>" was accessed, it will be removed in a future version
03-22 22:15:06.002 18359 18424 I python  : [WARNING] [Base        ] Unknown <android> provider
```

Comment: Bruno what change did you make? This seems to be the all important piece to solving this problem. Can you provide details on this please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kivy : Error weakly-referenced object (in a clock function) no longer exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61658224/kivy-error-weakly-referenced-object-in-a-clock-function-no-longer-exists)

Comment: I already solved it I had to change in .spec file in requirements to `kivy==2.0.0` and then `buildozer android clean` because for me deafult kivy version was v1.11.1. In version 2.0.0 this bug was fixed